# ActiveMerchant Authorize.net ARB and CIM Phone?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorize.net, activemerchant

I am unable to store phone number to either an ARB or CIM profile. Everything else stores perfect, but phone number won't save. We tried '1111111111' as well. Is :phone not the correct option name? Authorize.net has a field for phone number.

We are using the recurring in ARB:
http://activemerchant.rubyforge.org/classes/ActiveMerchant/Billing/AuthorizeNetGateway.html#M000399

```
options = {
    :billing_address => { 
      :name     => 'Mark McBride',
      :address1 => '1 Show Me The Money Lane',
      :city     => 'San Francisco',
      :state    => 'CA',
      :country  => 'US',
      :zip      => '23456',
      :phone    => '(555)555-5555'
    }
  }
```

Any help would be amazing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have phone number in the wrong place. Phone number goes under "customer". Not the billing information. Make sure to [read the documentation](http://www.authorize.net/support/ARB_guide.pdf) for the proper syntax for each request.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry delphi but you cannot pass phone number in billing address.

Comment: I don't think that is correct. Authorize.net has a field for phone number. If you go into the management console, you'll see it both under ARB and CIM.